# Why my redirect to a new VF page with command link does not work?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

[image]

When I click on the PB-005438 ({!p.Id}), wants to  redirect to a new VF page layout (gibco2) with all vlues. But when I click on it, gives me a error. Any idead Why is that?  Thanks.

```
<apex:page standardController="Product_Brief__c" extensions="DispatcherContactNewController">
    </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
            <apex:pageBlock title="Recent Product Briefs">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pbs}" var="p" >
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:commandLink action="{! assetClicked}" value="{!P.Name}" id="theCommandLink"> 
                        <apex:param value="{!P.Name}" name="id" assignTo="{!selectedAsset}" ></apex:param>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:column>
                     <apex:column value="{!p.RecordTypeId}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            </apex:pageBlock
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

**Extension**

```
public class DispatcherContactNewController {

    public DispatcherContactNewController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
                this.controller = controller;
            }

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setpb{
            get{
                if(setpb == null){
                    setpb = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                        [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId, Createddate FROM Product_Brief__c ORDER BY Createddate DESC ]));
                             setpb.setPageSize(10);
                             }
                             return setpb;
               } 
               set;
        }

        public List<Product_Brief__c>getpbs(){
            return (List<Product_Brief__c>)setpb.getrecords();
        }
/* ---------- For Redirect to New Page ------ */
 public string selectedAsset {get;set;}
    public PageReference assetClicked() 
    { 

    PageReference redirect = new PageReference('/apex/gibcopb2'); 

    // pass the selected asset ID to the new page
    redirect.getParameters().put('id',selectedAsset); 
    redirect.setRedirect(true); 

    return redirect;
    }
        }
```

Comment: Unless you have some processing you need to do in your controller, using an apex:outputLink will make your links more responsive as they will take the user in a single GET to the new object. The apex:commandLink (when you get it working) will first POST all the view state back to the server (2 seconds?) and then return a page which will tell the browser to GET the new object.

Comment: @KeithC Will apex:commandLink post the apex:param to server if its not having a rerender attribute?

Comment: @VigneshwaranG I believe so but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

`apex:commandLink` is not having `rerender` attribute thus not posting the value in `apex:param` to controller.

**Problem 2:**

If the `value` attribute is a bind variable in `apex:param` and the `name` attribute is a literal value, the value is not getting passed to controller.

Change the `name="id"` in the `apex:param` to `name="{!P.Name}"`